# Combining Rx Singles into Observables recursively

Tags: rx-java, kotlin, reactive-programming

Let's say I have a `Single` called `s_0` that can either emit an element `t_0` from type `T` or fail (that would be a `Single<T>` in some languages). That is:

```
s_0: -- t_0          // Success

OR

s_0: -- X            // Failure
```

Instances from type `T` have a `next()` method that return an optional `Single` from type `T` as well (a `Single<T>?` in **Kotlin**). This behavior leads to a chain of `Single` instances capable of emitting a chain of `T` instances, where each single `s_i` may emit an element `t_i` capable of returning a next single `s_i+1`, which will emit an element `t_i+1` and so on, until the last element `t_n-1` does not return a single or any of the singles fails:

```
s_0: -- t_0
        ↓
        s_1: -- t_1
                ↓
                s_2: -- t_2

                        ...

                        ↓
                        s_n-1: -- t_n-1
                                  ↓
                                  null

OR

s_0: -- t_0
        ↓
        s_1: -- t_1
                ↓
                s_2: -- t_2

                        ...

                        ↓
                        s_i: -- X
```

I'm looking for an **elegant** way to obtain an `Observable` `o` from type `T` capable of emitting all elements from the chain started by `s_0` finishing successfully when there are no more singles on the chain or failing if any single fails:

```
o: -- t_0 -- t_1 -- t_2 -- ... -- t_n-1 --o     // Success

OR

o: -- t_0 -- t_1 -- t_2 -- ... --X              // Failure
```

By **elegant**, I mean something as simple as this (in **Kotlin**):

```
// Get single somehow (out of the scope of this question)
val s0: Single<T> = provideSingle()

// Get observable
val o: Observable<T> = s0.chain()

// Define extension method
fun Single<T>.chain(): Observable<T> {
    /*
    Implement here
     */
}

// Element interface
interface T {
    fun next(): Single<T>?
}
```

## What's the applicability of this?

This scenario can be found when consuming a REST API with pagination, where `Single` instances can be used to retrieve individual pages, which can in turn provide `Single` instances capable of emitting subsequent pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested this but based on a solution I code some time ago to a similar pagination problem I translated to Kotlin

```
fun Single<T>.chain(): Observable<T> =
    toObservable()
    .concatWith {
        it.next()?.chain()
        ?: Observable.empty()
    }
```

The key to get that "recursive" chaining is the `concatWith` operator calling recursively the `chain` method

Comment: Cool! `concatMap` + recursion is the way to go. I'd just like to point out that, in this specific case, the given code won't work since the emitted item will never be `null` and it should be concatenated with the returned value recursively, something like: `concatMap { Observable.just(it).concatWith(it.next()?.chain(next) ?: Observable.empty()) }`. But that's just a small detail, your answer pointed me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I've just updated my answer to reflect that point. Just notice that your `chain()` method doesn't accept any `next` arg ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Q44535765 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Maybe<Element> first = get();
    first.toObservable()
        .compose(o -> chain(o))
        .doOnError(e -> System.out.println(e))
        .subscribe(
            e -> System.out.println(e),
            e -> System.out.println("fail"),
            () -> System.out.println("complete"));
  }

  static Maybe<Element> get() {
    return Maybe.just(
        () -> If.<Maybe<Element>> that(Math.random() > 0.1)
            .tobe(() -> get())
            .orbe(() -> If.<Maybe<Element>> that(Math.random() > 0.5)
                .tobe(() -> Maybe.empty())
                .orbe(() -> null)
                .result())
            .result());
  }

  static Observable<Element> chain(Observable<Element> s) {
    return s.concatMap(
        e -> Observable.just(e)
            .concatWith(e.next()
                .toObservable()
                .compose(o -> chain(o))));
  }

  interface Element {
    Maybe<Element> next();
  }
}
```

While `If` is my util class, you can instead by `if...else...`.